# Format number from stock pirce to number (double)

Tags: python

I have a price in db written this way $375,061.60 i want to change it to be able to make basic math operation to somting like this 375061.60.
I already use replace function but it doesnt remove dollar sign

```
replace("$","")
```

Comment: You use the replace function like so: `newstring = oldstring.replace("$","")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) should be used for money operations to avoid floating point inaccuracies.

```
from decimal import Decimal

val = Decimal( yourNumber.replace('$', '').replace(',', '') )
```

This assumes that the values in your DB always use a period to signify where the decimal point is, and not a comma, which some countries will use instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `re` to replace both the dollar sign and the comma then convert it to float:

```
import re
float(re.sub(r'[$,]', '', '$375,061.60'))
```

Output:

`375061.6`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round()`, `replace()`, and `float()` method like below to be able to make basic math operation:

```
round(float('$375,061.60'.replace(',', '').replace('$', '')), 2)
```

But as suggested by @hostingutilities.com, it's better to use `Decimal` for accuracy.

> Decimal used within financial applications that require a high degree
> of accuracy and easy to avoid rounding errors whereas Float used when
> you stores scientific numbers and for better performance.